# how to calculate loglikelihood for VAE/VQVAE

Tags: neural-networks, inference, variational-bayes

I asked this question on /r/MLQuestions aswell.

Although similar questions have been asked a few times here on reddit and elsewhere, I'm still unclear on how one would calculate the log-likelihood of, say, the CIFAR10 test set, under VAE/VQVAE models, as presented in

https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937

and related papers. A "black-box" method using tensorflow's tf.distributions (although for binarized MINST) can be found here

https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/vae.py

and here

https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/vq_vae.py

, but I would love to understand how this value is calculated "manually".

Would anyone care to elaborate on exactly how to estimate this reported value for CIFAR10? I mention this dataset specifically since it's used as benchmark in many recent papers, and since CIFAR10 isn't binary like binarized MNIST.

I'm very thankful for any help! :)

PS: I am aware of a previous explanation on how to convert the log-likelihood value to bits/dim here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/56m5o2/discussion_calculation_of_bitsdims/

but following this method requires that some loglikelihood (5371 in this case) has already been calculated (in the NICE code, this is done for the particular case)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

Variational autoencoders optimize only a lower bound on the likelihood, since the likelihood itself is intractable, so there is no easy way to calculate the likelihood.

However, Appendix D of the original paper, [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114) by
Diederik P Kingma and Max Welling, suggests how one might approximately estimate $p(x)$ when the latent space is low dimensional.

Comment: Can you please link to the appendix?

Comment: here it is, also edited it into the post https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114